# Logical Operators not subsetting as expected

Tags: r, boolean-logic

I am trying to create a subset of the rows that have a value of 1 for variable A, **and** a value of 1 for **at least one** of the following variables: B, C, or D.

```
Subset1 <-  subset(Data,
              Data$A==1 &
                Data$B ==1  ||
                Data$C ==1 |
                Data$D == 1,
              select= A)
Subset1
```

The problem is that the code above returns some  rows that have A=0 and I am not sure why.

To troublehsoot:

1. I know that **&&** and **||** are the long forms or **and** and **or** which vectorizes it. 
   I have run this code several times using  **&&**,  **||**,**&** and **|** in different places. Nothing returns what I am looking for exactly.
2. When I shorten the code, it works fine and I subset only the rows that I would expect:

`Subset1 <- subset(Data,
                       Data$A==1 &
                       Data$B==0,
                      select= A)`

`Subset1`

Unfortunately, this doesn't suffice since I also need to capture rows whose C or D value = 1.
Can anyone explain why my first code block is not subsetting what I am expecting it to?

Answer (score 3):

You can use parens to be more specific about what your `&` is referring to.  Otherwise (as @Patrick Trentin clarified) your logical operators are combined according to [operator precedence](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html) (within the same level of precedence they are evaluated from left to right).

Example:

```
> FALSE & TRUE | TRUE #equivalent to (FALSE & TRUE) | TRUE
[1] TRUE
> FALSE & (TRUE | TRUE)
[1] FALSE
```

So in your case you can try something like below (assuming you want items that `A == 1` `&` that meet one of the other conditions):

```
Data$A==1 & (Data$B==1 | Data$C==1 | Data$D==1)
```

Comment: *"Otherwise the bools will be combined from left to right"* nope, logical operators are combined according to **operator precedence** first, and only within the same level of precedence they are evaluated from left to right. In **R**, `&` and `&&` have higher priority than `|` and `||` according to this [manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html).

Comment: @PatrickTrentin thanks for the info and source. I'll make an edit once I get to a computer to avoid misinforming any future readers

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide the data you're working with, I've replicated some here.

```
set.seed(20)
Data = data.frame(A = sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE),
                  B = sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE),
                  C = sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE),
                  D = sample(0:1, 10, replace=TRUE))
```

If you use parenthesis, which can evaluate to a logical function, you can achieve what you're looking for.

```
Subset1 <- subset(Data,
                  Data$A==1 &
                    (Data$B == 1 |
                    Data$C == 1 |
                    Data$D ==1),
                  select=A)
Subset1
  A
1 1
2 1
4 1
5 1
```